# Use markers in After Effects as triggers for a random color animation after effects

Tags: expression, after-effects

How to change the color of a layer randomly in markers?

In After Effects i need expression code to randomly change the color of a layer when I hit the markers. please guide me. I myself could not find a code that would do this for me in this project. Thank you